# Laravel 5.6 login with google work in localhost but not work in hosting

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.6, laravel-socialite

Client error: `POST https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: { "error": "invalid_request", "error_description": "Missing required parameter: code" }

is there anybody to help me?

Comment: It can be for various reason .. you can try with refresh token ..

Comment: I've compared with with refresh token. a different error appears

Client error: `POST https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: { "error": "invalid_grant", "error_description": "Bad Request" }

the difference is **invalid_grant** and **invalid_request**.

my problem is on response *invalid_request.*